# How can I expand a relative path without expanding symlinks?

Tags: python, git

I have a path like:

```
/home/me/work/project/a/b/c
```

Which, is actually uses an awful symlink like:

```
/home/me/work -> /mnt/device/volume/storage/work/me/
```

I'm using git to show the top-level of the git clone which is:

```
/home/me/work/project
```

If I use:

```
$ git rev-parse --show-toplevel
/mnt/device/volume/storage/work/me/project
```

I get the full expanded absolute path.  I don't want that.  So, I can use:

```
$ git rev-parse --show-cdup
../../..
```

to get the relative path to the top

Now, I would just love it if I could figue out how to get python to expand that relative path to:

```
/home/me/work/project
```

instead of:

```
/mnt/device/volume/storage/work/me/project
```

Is this possible?

Comment: Think pretty much everything in Python is going to traverse the link for you.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

How about:

```
>>> import os
>>> os.path.normpath(os.path.join(os.environ['PWD'], '../../..'))
'/home/me/work/project'
```

`os.path.normpath` doesn't follow symlinks; it does not even care if the file system exists. It simply computes what the normalized path *would be* after eliminating double slashes and double dots.

Comment: The problem is that to get '/home/me/work/project/a/b/c', I would need to get it with os.getcwd() which expands the symlinks.

Comment: How do you know that you are at the location `/home/me/work/project/a/b/c` then?

Comment: That's the pwd when I invoke the script that I'm using.  I need a script that can show the toplevel of the current git repo without expanding the symlinks.

Comment: Try `os.environ['PWD']` in that case.

Comment: That works.  When I use that in combination with your suggestion, I should be able to get what I want.  It just kinda sucks that I have to do all that